# PhpStorm ftp without downloading all files

Tags: ftp, phpstorm

I just switched to the php editor PhpStorm. With other editors I have used, editing files through ftp went like this:

1. Browse the file in the explorer
2. Open the file in the editor
3. Make changes
4. Press save

This would automatically first download that single file and show it in the editor, and then upload that file to the server with the changes.

Now I'm trying to add an ftp connection in PhpStorm, but it immediately downloads all files to my pc. Is there a way to have the workflow I just described on PhpStorm, without downloading the whole server.

Comment: Yes and No. **No** -- you cannot edit files directly over FTP -- it has to be downloaded locally. **Yes** -- you can download and edit only desired files -- no need to get whole project. For that -- if you are using "New Project Wizard" -- uncheck all unwanted folders/files; better -- just create brand new **empty** project and configure FTP access manually -- now you will be able to browser Remote Host and download file only when needed. Automatic upload on Save can be configured in Settings.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I now created a new empty project, but how do i add ftp to that?

Comment: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Deployments+in+PhpStorm --- `Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Deployment`

Comment: **P.S.** Fresh news: as of **next v9 EAP build** it should be possible to edit files "directly" over FTP (and alike) -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-1398#comment=27-984934 . If you want to try it (new EAP build) when it will be published -- please watch [PhpStorm blog](http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) for new post. P.P.S. v9 EAP builds can be run alongside with current v8 (they store IDE-wide settings is separate folders)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is uncompleted answer for that,

```
File > New Project from Existing file ... > web server ... via FTP/SFTP/FTPS.
```

Than fill the forms to the end, The local project on the left will be empty.

chose `Tools > Deployment > Browse Remote Host.`

This will show the Host files and folders on the right.

`Double click` to open the file and `Alt+Shift+Q` to upload it.

**Why uncompleted answer?**
Because when you open multi files and edit some, you will not know which are edited and not uploaded from the unedited files.

-Phpstorm 2016.3.2

Comment: `from existing file... ftp` -> `source files are downloaded to project root, then synchronized with server when necessary.`. This exactly happens. If you press finish, everything gets downloaded. on my server, there are about 40 GB of files. this is just horrible

Comment: also, is there really no way to simply browse a remote host without creating a project for it? (like filezilla)

Comment: No blauhirn, it still is a IDE not a ftp browser

Comment: eclipse can do that - weird that PHPStorm can't... looking for the same, since eclipse has outdated ecryptions and I can't connect to the SFTP on my host anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `File > New Project from Existing file ... > web server ... via FTP/SFTP/FTPS.`.
In the last screen, where you set the project root, select the correct folder as project root **and also select it as `exclude from download`**

Save your project and you're good to go. No download happens.

Answer (score -2):

Please refer my tutorial which explains how to access remote files using ftp . We can edit the files and automatically upload the files to the server on save.

http://www.pearlbells.co.uk/edit-remote-files-phpstorm/

Main steps :

- Select File->New project from Existing files
- Select the checkbox as shown in fig (refer blog for images) and click next.
- Enter projectname
- From the dropdown select ‘On explicit save atcion’
- Add new remote server
- Enter Ftp details
- Select the remote path.

Refer the tutorial for demo images and explanation.

Comment: The question was about creating the project from existing files without downloading all the contents

Comment: Your answer is working for me to download the remote file and edit it with a local backup.